# How to create a page that lists custom taxonomies with links?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, list

I want to create a page that lists all the Custom Taxonomies, with each item linking to a page that will list all the terms in a given taxonomy.

I can produce a list of taxonomies using this

```
 <?php 
$args=array(
  'public'   => true,
  '_builtin' => false

); 
$output = 'names'; // or objects
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
$taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output,$operator); 
if  ($taxonomies) {
  foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>'. $taxonomy. '</p>' ;
  }
}
?>
```

But of course no links.

Looking at the codex there is very little information on the parameters - at least for neophyte like myself.

Any suggestions on how to output a link for each custom taxonomy?

Thanks

Comment: Taxonomies don't have archive pages like that, so there's nothing really to link to in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get `$taxonomy` you can perform further logic:

```
$tax = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );

if( isset( $tax->has_archive ) && $tax->has_archive == true ) {
    // do output. archive will be wordpress_url + $taxonomy->name
    ?>
    <p>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url( $taxonomy->name ); ?>">
            <?php echo $tax->labels->name; ?>
        </a>
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

This is untested, but you get the idea.